# How to use a function in two packages in Scala?

Tags: scala, package

I have two packages in Scala: `package foo` and `package bar`. Both have a `Utils` object in them that has same methods `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()`. Code looks like this:

Inside package foo

```
object Utils{
def doSomething()
def doSomethingElse()
}
```

Inside package bar

```
object Utils{
def doSomething()
def doSomethingElse()
}
```

Is there a way I can provide a common ground from where both the packages can use the methods in `Utils` object? I want to avoid code duplication. What I have in mind is to write a package object in one of the packages and import that in the other package. But is there a better way to eliminate code duplication?

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more? I don't understand what you really need to achieve. Could you give an example?

Comment: @Peter added more information. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

package objects can inherit from other traits, abstract classes and classes, just like any other object.  Simply provide the methods in an appropriately named trait and include it in both:

```
trait SomethingHandler {
  def doSomething() = ???
  def doSomethingElse() = ???
}

package object foo extends SomethingHandler

package object bar extends SomethingHandler
```

Alternatively, you can use an object and import it into both package namespaces:

```
object SomethingHandler {
  def doSomething() = ???
  def doSomethingElse() = ???
}

package object foo {
  import some.package.SomethingHandler._
}

package object bar {
  import some.package.SomethingHandler._
}
```

Comment: The second solution doesn't work if you want to call those methods in package `foo`; only in the package object itself.

Comment: Absolutely correct - in which case using an alias for each object works, as in [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27944243/135978).

Answer (score 2):

Place the `Utils` object in a separate package `util` and import it where you use it?
Or else alias it in your package objects:

```
package object foo {
  val Utils = util.Utils
}
```

If they don't have all their methods in common, factor out common methods in a trait:

```
trait Common {
  def doSomething() = ???
  def doSomethingElse() = ???
}

object Utils extends Common {
  ...
}
```